# applying css to <html:link> tags

Tags: css, button, struts, struts-html

I'm starting out in using struts and I'm finding difficulty in applying my css on the   tags.

```
<html:link action="LoginLink" styleClass="loginButton"/>
```

Basically I'd want to apply a button image on a link which goes to a login page.

I've used this method successfully in submit buttons for forms and I thought that the same could apply to the links, however it was not displaying properly.

```
<html:submit styleClass="submitButton" value=" " ></html:submit>
```

To add, I am able to see the top part of my button image when I place some text on the link like for example:

```
<html:link action="LoginLink" styleClass="loginButton" >Some text here</html:link>
```

Are there any alternative tags that I am able to use or is there any way to set the height and width (in pixels) of the link tag so that the button can appear normally?

also here is the css for the loginButton for reference:

```
.loginButton {
    border:none;
    background:url('../images/adminbutton.png');
    height: 59px;
    width: 138px;
}.loginButton:hover {
    background:url('../images/adminbutton2.png');

}.loginButton:active {
    position:relative;
    top:1px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to add this property

```
display: block;
```

to .loginButton

Comment: This works to a certain extent, while the image was able to display, the clickable area of the link is bigger than the image, so there is a blank area where I am able to click. I'm hoping that this is a step towards the right direction as I need to only reduce the clickable area to be the same as my image size. If there are any follow ups to this approach it would be appreciated.

Comment: Set margin and padding properties to 0, or maybe you should edit this image and cut off the white space around the button(if there is a white space).

Comment: The button has no excess whitespace, and also tried setting the margin and padding, but to no avail. :(

Comment: Image size is exactly the same like height&width property in CSS style ?

Comment: ok I found the culplit, it seems that the css had the incorrect height and width for the image which caused the misrender, problem solved, thanks!!